# How do I strip the url of a google news json feed link

Tags: php

How do I strip the url of a google news json feed link?

My link looks like this

http%253A%252F%252Fwww.boston.com%252Fbusiness%252Fnews%252F2014%252F12%252F04%252Fnasa-poised-usher-new-era-with-orion-launch%252FGOh9asOZiRJPHbNw60otUK%252Fstory.html

I have used the following code

```
strip_tags("".$row['url']."");
```

This does not do anything, I'm guessing this is possible and I am using the wrong php function.

Comment: what do you want to obtain as result?

Comment: i would like it to show http://boston.com/business/news etc etc

Comment: just a normal url so when a user clicks on it it will show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for this.

```
$url = "http%253A%252F%252Fwww.boston.com%252Fbusiness%252Fnews%252F2014%252F12%252F04%252Fnasa-poised-usher-new-era-with-orion-launch%252FGOh9asOZiRJPHbNw60otUK%252Fstory.html";
$url = urldecode(urldecode($url));
echo $url; // Will output: http://www.boston.com/business/news/2014/12/04/nasa-poised-usher-new-era-with-orion-launch/GOh9asOZiRJPHbNw60otUK/story.html
```

Comment: Maybe he will have to use urlDecode twice as his URL seems to be double encoded

Comment: Indeed it seems so, I have updated my post. Thank you for the comment.